# “Uncle's jokes !?”

Tags: culture, puns

I recently heard about something that would be roughly translated as “uncle's jokes” (the Japanese word for it should be something like 伯父ネタ or 伯父ガル but I can't remember correctly what I heard the only part where I am sure is that it started with 叔父/伯父).

Basically, it is just a play on words (by playing on the phonetic similarities of different words). Right now, I am only able to remember one.

> 猫寝込んだ。（ねこねこんだ）

My question is how is it called and would you know some more?

Comment: 「おやじギャグ」じゃないかな？「布団が吹っ飛んだ」とか・・　For more: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%A4%E3%82%B8%E3%82%AE%E3%83%A3%E3%82%B0

Comment: That's exactly that. You should post it as an answer because it perfectly answers my question.

Comment: Stupid example: you arrive at someone's house for a slumber party.  Upon entering the house, you say, 「パジャマ着ます！」 It's basically just dumb puns, and given the large number of homophones or near-homophones in Japanese, there's lots of room to play around.  :)

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi そういえばNHKの番組のコーナーに「[パジャマでおじゃま](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/75218XzxnNE/hqdefault.jpg)」ってのがありましたっけ。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called おやじギャグ and is also called ダジャレ.

Here are 100 examples: http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2136602894164225401

Comment: おやじ in the phrase おやじギャグ matches the "dad" in the English phrase "dad joke" -- it's the kind of dumb joke that generally only a dad would tell.  :)